# Camera premission issues

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-permissions

on accepting the permission by overidering onRequestPermissionsResult it can open camera and if we dont accept  the premission it will deny opening camera what i want is when clicking allow once it should ask premission again

this are the 3 options that we will get for premission

[image: img]

this is my code for onRequestPermissionsResult

```
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            Log.e("Camera", "Capturing Image == ")

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, proceed with capturing the image (call captureImage())
                captureImage()
                Log.e("Camera", "Capturing Image == ")
            } else {
                // Permission denied, handle accordingly (e.g., show a message)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        // Handle other permission requests if needed
    }
```

thanks in advance

i'm expecting to ask permission if we select allow once